# Sum of a Complex array

Tags: c#, complex-numbers

I have a few Complex arrays, created like this :

```
System.Numerics.Complex[] ValeurPixelsExperiment = new System.Numerics.Complex[132];
System.Numerics.Complex[] ValeurPixelsReference = new System.Numerics.Complex[132];
System.Numerics.Complex[] ValeurPixelsSumExperiment = new System.Numerics.Complex[1024];
System.Numerics.Complex[] ValeurPixelsSumReference = new System.Numerics.Complex[1024];
```

The first two arraysare populated with the Blue component of the color of a serie of pixels from a `Bitmap Couleur`. Here, the complex numbers all have an imaginary part 0. Now I want each member of the last two arrays to be the sum of all the members of on of the first two arrays (once again, Imaginary parts will be 0), but I can't find an "easy" way to do it without adding loops inside my loops, which I'm not so much fond of.

I know I could use int or float numbers instead of complex, and that is what I was doing initially, but as I intend to use the Fast Fourier Transform function from the AForge.NET framework, I need my data to be in the Complex form. So I can't just use .Sum()

I hope I am being clear enough ! Anyone got an idea how to achieve this ?

Here is my code, with the remnant .Sum() from my use of float numbers, which doesn't work :

```
for (int i = 1; i < 1024; i++)
{
     for (int j = 157; j < 288; j++)
     {
          ValeurPixelsExperiment[j - 156] = Couleur.GetPixel(i, j).B; 
     }
     ValeurPixelsSumExperiment[i] = ValeurPixelsExperiment //.Sum(); I NEED HELP HERE

     for (int j = 484; j < 615; j++)
     {
          ValeurPixelsReference[j - 483] = Couleur.GetPixel(i, j).B; 
     }
     ValeurPixelsSumReference[i] = ValeurPixelsReference //.Sum(); AND HERE
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linq `Sum()` *doesn't support* `Complex` items as an argument; I suggest `Aggregate`, e.g.:

```
// Aggeregate items in ValeurPixelsReference by summing them up
ValeurPixelsSumReference[i] = ValeurPixelsReference.Aggregate((s, a) => s + a);
```